# Get notified when a row is insert in mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core

I have a MySQL database with a table `bookings`. When a user makes a booking on a web api, the data of this booking is written into this table.

But after that another bot (C#) has to use this data to do some actions with it that cannot be done by the webserver.

So how does this bot know when new data is added to the database table?
The obvious answer would be to let the bot pool every second to see if a new row is added. But this sounds very inefficiently. Is there another way to get notified when there is new data added to a mysql table?

Comment: `triggers` in the table

Comment: You can use trigger after insert is done. Or you can use utility which will make DB call every 1 min interval.

Comment: How do I get a notification to another application from a mysql trigger?

Comment: If your DB is same, then it is possible when any data is added in table & trigger will raise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Receiving notification from external system (MySQL in your case) is a bad idea. You'll end up creating a hard wired infrastructure.

Polling Every minute is even worse. You'll end up creating a very slow and ineffective system.

If you own the WebAPI code there are other better things that you can do.
WebAPI should only save data through Unit of Work Pattern (or CQRS). 
The Unit of Work, through repository pattern and ORM (Entity Framework) would know the details of data persistance (MySQL in your case)

I would implement it using Domain Driven Design concept called Domain Events.

Vladimir Khorikov has an amazing course about the topic on Pluralsight.

[Domain Events Example Code on Github](https://github.com/vkhorikov/DddInAction/tree/master/DddInPractice.Logic/Common)

1. WebAPI receives request to insert data
2. WebAPI triggers Domain Event Change
3. Domain Event Change handler inserts the data in database using Unit of Work or CQRS patterns.
4. All the other components that should get notification that new data has arrived should also handle this event and take action accordingly.

In Summary, consider switching to Domain Driven Design and use Domain Events and your application will be a lot flexible, Micro-services and cloud ready.

Comment: I already have it set up this way. Brilliant, that I didn't come up with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like polling the database, which could be a perfectly fine solution, the other bot needs to recieve a message about new data. Where does this message come from? You could send it from the web api. How to do that depends on what kind of thing your second bot is (a service?) Using a trigger seems wrong to me, since it requires the database to be aware of the other bot.

Comment: After 'Googling' some time I think you are right. Pooling is probably the best sollution.